# Uploading In IE6 With Fiddler is Faster?

Tags: internet-explorer-6, fiddler

In our asp.net application we have an upload feature.  When Fiddler is running on the client (with Act as a system proxy) the upload is quick (10megs in 20 sec).  however, when Fiddler is not up on the client it's taking about 5 minutes.  Any one have any suggestions?

Comment: Man, now IE6 won't ever go away!!  People will just have Fiddler running with it to make things faster.  :)

Comment: Seriously, that's pretty strange.  Are there any other differences between the scenarios (protocol - http vs. https, port used, different server, etc.)?

Comment: After doing some reading, it appears Fiddler replaces settings when running.  One in particular is the SocketSendBufferLength which appears to be our bottle neck in ie6

Comment: Same server and protocol

Comment: Fiddler isn't replacing that setting, but as a local proxy, it's buffering the complete POST request locally (so the small buffer doesn't matter) and then blasting it to the server as quickly as the server will take it.

The send buffer size was increased in later browser versions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Converting to answer*

Fiddler isn't replacing that setting, but as a local proxy, it's buffering the complete POST request locally (so the small buffer doesn't matter) and then blasting it to the server as quickly as the server will take it. The send buffer size was increased in later browser versions.

For IE6, see the steps in http://support.microsoft.com/kb/329781 to adjust the buffer size.